# What does a double parenthesis in a function call do?

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm using [dlib](http://dlib.net).

I came across the following in one of the example programs:

`cout << "p(D=0) = " << solution.probability(D)(0) << endl;`

I've never seen a double parenthesis after a function call in C++. What does it do and how does it work?

Comment: I would guess that `solution.probability(D)` return a single parameter functor, which you then call with argument `0`.

Comment: probability(D) likely returns a function pointer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: `probability` is a function returning another function pointer, `std::function`, etc. Its return value is called again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What does `solution.probability(D)` return.  If it's a functional object, or a pointer to a function, you can call it, which is probably what the second set of parentheses do.

Comment: const double probability (
            const assignment& a
        ) const;
        /*!
            ensures
                - returns the probability p(X == a)
        !*/

Comment: Thank you. Is this a common thing to do?

Comment: @Pétur It depends somewhat on the application domain, but I wouldn't consider it rare.  On the other hand: the function you cite seems to return just a `double`, _not_ a pointer to function or a functional object.